# Display DIV during the news hours using PHP

Tags: php

I have a wordpress site. I need to display a DIV during the news hours. So I have a function in template-functions. It looks like this:

```
function kiroj_live_news() {
$week_day = date('w');
$current_time = date('Hi');

$show_news_div = false;
if ($week_day >= 1 && $week_day <= 5)
{
  if (($current_time >= '0430' && $current_time <= '0800') || ($current_time >= '1200' && $current_time <= '1300') || ($current_time >= '1700' && $current_time <= '1830') || ($current_time >= '2300' && $current_time <= '2330'))
  {
    $show_news_div = true;
  }
}
if ($week_day == 6)
{
  if (($current_time >= '0700' && $current_time <= '0830') || ($current_time >= '1700' && $current_time <= '1800') || ($current_time >= '1830' && $current_time <= '1900') || ($current_time >= '2300' && $current_time <= '2330'))
  {
    $show_news_div = true;
  }
}

if ($week_day == 0)
{
  if (($current_time >= '0600' && $current_time <= '0700') || ($current_time >= '1700' && $current_time <= '1800') || ($current_time >= '1830' && $current_time <= '1900') || ($current_time >= '2300' && $current_time <= '2359'))
  {
    $show_news_div = true;
  }
}
}
```

In the area I want my DIV to display in, I have an if:

```
<?php 
        $display = kiroj_live_news ();

        if ($display)
        {
          ?>
            <div class="live-news"><a href="http://www.kirotv.com/videos/news/kiro-newscast-hd2/vCYwYn/" target="_blank">Breaking News</a></div>
          <?php
        }

    ?>
```

I have changed the times in my main function, tried other date() formats from the PHP manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and I cannot get the DIV to display. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

```
function kiroj_live_news() {

    //your code here

    ....

    return $show_news_div;

}

$display = kiroj_live_news();

......
```

Your function doesn't return anything - so it's always `FALSE`.

Comment: what do I need to do to make it return?